# javaMail API force SSL encryption for SMTP authentication

Tags: android, ssl, jakarta-mail

I want to send an eMail via smtp server. So I use javaMail API.
my properties are:

```
Properties emailProperties = new Properties();  
emailProperties.setProperty("mail.host", emailHost); 
emailProperties.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtps");
emailProperties.put("mail.smtps.auth", "true");   
emailProperties.setProperty("mail.smtps.ssl.enable", "true");
emailProperties.setProperty("mail.smtps.ssl.required", "true");
emailProperties.put("mail.smtps.port", emailPort);   
emailProperties.put("mail.smtps.socketFactory.port", "465");
emailProperties.put("mail.smtps.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");   
emailProperties.put("mail.smtps.socketFactory.fallback", "false");   
emailProperties.setProperty("mail.smtps.quitwait", "false"); 
Log.i("GMail", "Mail server properties set.");
mailSession = Session.getInstance(emailProperties, this);
mailSession.setDebug(true);
```

when I check the Log, I get:

```
08-29 07:58:50.037: I/System.out(2652): DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc.,1.4.1]
08-29 07:58:50.107: I/System.out(2652): DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
08-29 07:58:50.107: I/System.out(2652): DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
08-29 07:58:50.107: I/System.out(2652): DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "mail.gmx.net", port 465, isSSL false
08-29 07:58:51.517: I/System.out(2652): 220 gmx.com (mrgmx001) Nemesis ESMTP Service ready
08-29 07:58:51.517: I/System.out(2652): DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "mail.gmx.net", port: 465
08-29 07:58:51.647: I/System.out(2652): EHLO localhost
08-29 07:58:51.717: I/System.out(2652): 250-gmx.com Hello localhost [158.181.89.31]
08-29 07:58:51.717: I/System.out(2652): 250-SIZE 69920427
08-29 07:58:51.717: I/System.out(2652): 250 AUTH LOGIN PLAIN
08-29 07:58:51.807: I/System.out(2652): DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "69920427"
08-29 07:58:51.807: I/System.out(2652): DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "LOGIN PLAIN"
08-29 07:58:51.807: I/System.out(2652): DEBUG SMTP: Attempt to authenticate
08-29 07:58:51.817: I/System.out(2652): AUTH LOGIN
08-29 07:58:51.897: I/System.out(2652): 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
08-29 07:58:51.907: I/System.out(2652): cmFtc2NoZmFjaEBnbXgubmV0
08-29 07:58:51.977: I/System.out(2652): 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
08-29 07:58:51.977: I/System.out(2652): RkZ3UzIwMDM=
08-29 07:58:52.117: I/System.out(2652): 235 Authentication succeeded
08-29 07:58:52.187: I/System.out(2652): DEBUG SMTP: use8bit false
08-29 07:58:52.187: I/System.out(2652): MAIL FROM:<xxxx>
08-29 07:58:52.317: I/System.out(2652): 250 Requested mail action okay, completed
08-29 07:58:52.327: I/System.out(2652): RCPT TO:<yyyy>
08-29 07:58:52.387: I/System.out(2652): 250 OK
08-29 07:58:52.397: I/System.out(2652): DEBUG SMTP: Verified Addresses
08-29 07:58:52.397: I/System.out(2652): DEBUG SMTP:   yyyy
08-29 07:58:52.397: I/System.out(2652): DATA
08-29 07:58:52.467: I/System.out(2652): 354 Start mail input; end with <CRLF>.<CRLF>
08-29 07:58:52.657: I/System.out(2652): From: "xxxx" <xxxx>
08-29 07:58:52.657: I/System.out(2652): Sender: xxxx
08-29 07:58:52.657: I/System.out(2652): To: yyyy
08-29 07:58:52.657: I/System.out(2652): Message-ID: <-1321208264.0.1409313530035.JavaMail.root@mail.gmx.net>
08-29 07:58:52.657: I/System.out(2652): Subject: test
08-29 07:58:52.657: I/System.out(2652): MIME-Version: 1.0
08-29 07:58:52.667: I/System.out(2652): Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
08-29 07:58:52.727: I/System.out(2652): Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
08-29 07:58:52.727: I/System.out(2652): 
08-29 07:58:52.727: I/System.out(2652): bla blub
08-29 07:58:52.727: I/System.out(2652): .
08-29 07:58:52.797: I/System.out(2652): 250 Requested mail action okay, completed: id=0LcBBl-1Y6oXB3y7R-00jVvK
08-29 07:58:52.797: I/System.out(2652): QUIT
```

What I don't understand is, that I set `mail.transport.protocol` to `smtps` but when you read the log, there you could see `AUTH LOGIN PLAIN` and in `PROVIDER` you could read `smtp`.
What is missing there? I want to force SSL encryption or is my password, user name and text already send encrypted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the way you've (unnecessarily) set a socket factory, it's using SSL but not telling you that it's using SSL.  Start by correcting these [common mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).

Comment: when I remove the `socetFactory`-Properties then `isSSL` is set to true.
But at `AUTH` there is still `LOGIN PLAIN`. What does this mean? Are my username and password send encrypted or not?

Comment: They are.  If isSSL is true, it's made the connection over SSL.  You can use a network level packet monitor to verify.